# Changing chart options dynamically in Chart.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, class, chart.js

I have a page where I load different charts dynamically which update themselves with new data from an SQL-table.
They have maximum and minimum limits and I can make the dots on the line charts change color if they breach their limits (if too high or too low they become red , otherwise they are green)

Sadly, when I try changing the charts animation option, or bezierCurves option it does not respond to it, I looked on the chartjs page's documentation and could only find how to set these options when creating the chart... I need to do this on an interval based function after the charts are made depending on user input... i.e.

I have a collection of radio buttons : 
Animated - Not animated - bezierCurves - No bezierCurves

See on pic :)

[image: Charts Page]

They each set their respectable variable to true / false depending wether they are checked. 
Then , every time I update the charts , i try to change the options to the value of the variables (if they differ from the old ones)

Let me give you some code to clairify :)

Update function :

```
    // Standard values for all charts
$old_animation = true;
$old_curved = true;

// Start Update funtion for the test chart
setInterval(function update() {

// Set the new options value from the entered user input (on the site)
$curved = $('#curved').val();
    $animation = $('#animation').val();
    if ( $old_animation != $animation || $old_curved != $curved) {

        test_chart.options.animation = $animation;
        test_chart.options.bezierCurves = $curved;

        // Tried the following as well
        //test_chart.animation = $animation;
        //test_chart.options.animation = $animation;


        $old_animation = $animation;
        $old_curved = $curved;
    }

    // Set dataset point 0 value to that of point 1, point 1 to that of point 2 and so on...
    test_chart.datasets[0].points[0].value = test_chart.datasets[0].points[1].value;
    test_chart.datasets[0].points[1].value = test_chart.datasets[0].points[2].value;
    test_chart.datasets[0].points[2].value = test_chart.datasets[0].points[3].value;
    test_chart.datasets[0].points[3].value = test_chart.datasets[0].points[4].value;
    test_chart.datasets[0].points[4].value = test_chart.datasets[0].points[5].value;
    test_chart.datasets[0].points[5].value = test_chart.datasets[0].points[6].value;
    test_chart.scale.xLabels[0] = test_chart.scale.xLabels[1];
    test_chart.scale.xLabels[1] = test_chart.scale.xLabels[2];
    test_chart.scale.xLabels[2] = test_chart.scale.xLabels[3];
    test_chart.scale.xLabels[3] = test_chart.scale.xLabels[4];
    test_chart.scale.xLabels[4] = test_chart.scale.xLabels[5];
    test_chart.scale.xLabels[5] = test_chart.scale.xLabels[6];

    // Get the latest SQL value from the live feed div (hidden) and put that in the last data point
    $live_test = $('#live_test').html();
    $live_test = parseInt($live_test);
    $live_test = $live_test / <?php echo $column_numerator; ?>;

    // Get the last update time for the label of the last data point
    $live_updated = $('#live_updated').html().substr(11);
    test_chart.scale.xLabels[6] = $live_updated;
    test_chart.datasets[0].points[6].value = $live_test;
    console.log('Latest test value = ' + $live_test + ' this has been updated @: ' + $live_updated);




    temperature_chart.update();
}, 4000);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not correct. To change the options use `chart.options` where `chart = this.chart`.

Instead of updating the data, go through the `chart` object to update the data.
Then use `chart.update()`. This uses the click event to see if only one legend is displaying. If it is then it displays the data labels.

```
legend: {
    display: true,
    onClick: function (e, legendItem) {
        var index = legendItem.datasetIndex;
        var ci = this.chart;
        var meta = ci.getDatasetMeta(index);

        // See controller.isDatasetVisible comment
        meta.hidden = meta.hidden === null ? !ci.data.datasets[index].hidden : null;
        var cnt = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < ci.data.datasets.length; i++) {
            if (!ci.data.datasets[i]._meta[0].hidden) {
                cnt++;
            }
        }
        if (cnt === 1) {
            ci.options.plugins.datalabels.display = true;
        }
        else {
            ci.options.plugins.datalabels.display = false;
        }
        ci.update();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the options can only be set when the chart is created, it sounds like you need to recreate/redraw the charts when you have new options to use. You could set a listener on the radio buttons to recreate the charts with the new options.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to avoid :)