# How do I access chart.js options dynamically?

Tags: javascript, chart.js

I have a chart.js chart object `myBarChart` initially created with the options object

```
options={
    scaleOverride : true,
    scaleSteps : ymax,
    scaleStepWidth : 1,
    scaleStartValue : 0, 

    ...
}
```

where `ymax` is calculated to act as a 'suggestedMax'.

Users add data to the chart by clicking on its bars; the update function accesses the data as

```
myBarChart.datasets[0].bars[i].value = newValue[i]
```

(looping over all histogram bins).  This pattern, along with the [documentation](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html), suggests that I ought to be able to access the options as

```
myBarChart.options.scaleSteps = newYmax;
myBarChart.update();
```

in order to change the maximum of the y-axis as users add data.  However, this does not work.  When users add enough data to exceed the original `ymax`, the data is recorded, but the y-axis never changes, so the bar is cut off at the top.

I've tried setting an explicit value instead of `newYmax` and I see the same behavior, so the problem isn't in my calculation of `newYmax`.  I'm just not able to alter myBarChart.options.scaleSteps, and I can't figure out why.

I'm using v1.0.1 (upgrading is not an option).  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347109/changing-chart-options-dynamically-in-chart-js) indicates that options can't be changed after creation and that the chart must be redrawn, but I can't find any documentation to support that.

Can I access and change chart.js options after the chart is created?

Answer (score 3):

To update the options, you either update individual properties or update the entire object.  Then you must force a redraw on the chart for the new chart options to take effect (see [chartjs docs](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/developers/updates.html)).

For example:

```
const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart").getContext('2d');
const chart = new ChartJS(ctx, { title: { text: 'old title' } });
chart.options.title.text = 'new title';
chart.update();
```

Comment: This is what I'm doing, and what's not working.  I've edited my question to clarify that I am using the `update()` function.  The chart axes still don't update.

Comment: Right, scroll down the docs, it mentions how to update the scales supposedly.

Comment: Also, ensure that scaleSteps is a valid property within the configuration object. It could be that your initial setter for scaleSteps is incorrect which results in ChartJS overriding the property with the default behaviour.  Therefore if it is incorrect, you will not be able to update that same property.

Answer (score 1):

```
//get object
const chartJS: Chart = $("#myChart").data('chart');

//change something
chartJS.config.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.min = minVal <= 0 ? minVal : minVal - 

//update
chartJS.update();
```

make sure you add the object as data after creation

```
....
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: chartData,
                options
            });

//
var canvasItem = $("#myChart");
canvasItem.data('chart', myChart);
```